# Join Multiple Tables That Have Names with Same Prefix

Tags: mysql, sql, join, prefix

Is there a way to join all tables that have names that begin with same Prefix?

For example with tables having same prefix Customer_Feedback10, Customer_Feedback11, Customer_Feedback12, Customer_Feedback13 etc. These all have same column names and structure. I would like to join all and do a `SELECT * FROM`.

I know I can get all the table names using:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Customer_Feedback%'
```

What I want to achieve is join all the tables beginning with the Prefix "Customer_Feedback". Then display the data.

Comment: This might help:
https://www.daniweb.com/programming/databases/threads/516567/mysql-select-all-rows-from-all-tables

Comment: @Brian Tompsett Thanks for proper formatting.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. Anyway, it sounds like you want a UNION rather than a JOIN

Comment: @Strawberry You damn right. "Poor Design". Its a nightmare since the database is in  production and now I have to figure out a way to restructure it without shutting everything down.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in MySQL to do that but you can try making some procedure with prepared statement to make dynamic join statement.

Comment: good to know that straight up. Now that I know dynamic join may be the only way out, I would have to decide if I should just begin a structure change to the whole database before it grows too large. I fear dynamic statement for this could mess things up pretty bad as the database grows and throw up junk data. Really don't trust my skills at writing complex dynamic statements. So I avoid them like a plague. Can you give an example statement can I start off with and work on?

Comment: @CmailUltimate quite stuck with work but I do remember answering some dynamic query in past